# Chrome JavaScript Console autoselecting the search bar?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

Whenever I open the JavaScript developer console in Google Chrome, it automatically selects a search bar that appears at the top of the window. I don't know how to disable the search bar, or otherwise make sure that it isn't automatically selected when I open it. I'd rather have the actual console preselected instead of the search bar. How can I fix this?

Thank you!

Comment: This is the Console tab. I also noticed that this only occurs on my desktop, but not my laptop. Maybe there's a setting I checked to have this search bar show up accidentally in the first place? How might I hide it?

Comment: I think I see what you mean: the additional mini-console on the bottom behaves like that when Filtering toolbar is shown (I hide it usually). Anyway, it seems to be fixed in Chrome dev/canary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out; at some point I had enabled the filter by clicking on its button to do it (next to the "Clear Console" button). Just disabled it and it's all good now.

In the below image, the filter button is the second from the left (in between the "Clear Console" button and the "top" dropdown for Chome extensions).

[image: Location of filter button]